# How to let the role "editor" to control the menu?

Tags: menus, admin-menu

How to let the role "editor" to control the menu 
the only code i found was

```
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );
```

but i couldn't use it

Comment: "but i couldn't use it" - what do you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this to your **functions.php**

```
// Allow editors to see Appearance menu
$role_object = get_role( 'editor' );
$role_object->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
function hide_menu() {
 
    // Hide theme selection page
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' );
 
    // Hide widgets page
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' );
 
    // Hide customize page
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['themes.php'][6]);
 
}
 
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_menu');
```

[Source](https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-allow-editors-to-manage-menus)

Comment: I really searched about it and found this reply but i don't want to show all  this  stuff " themes , customize , widget menus "

Comment: I need the code to let the editor control the menus only

Comment: I changed the code, try this now

Comment: roles are for more than menu display. enabling such a permission to someone which is not an admin, should not be done just to be able to have some more stuff in the menu. For example removing the widgets from the menu will not prevent the user from modifying them via the customizer.

Comment: @mark i will test and add an update, but do you have any alternate solution so i can add it too?

Comment: no, I don't think it is possible to be more granular, but the problem is really with the bad question, as obviously he wants for the editor to be able to do stuff, not just see text in the menu ;)